# Use Protocol classes with torch.nn.Module

Tags: python, inheritance, pytorch, protocols

I would like to create a Protocol class to specify types of PyTorch models - is it possible to create a Protocol that inherits from torch.nn.Module?
Something like this:

```
class DiffusionModelProtocol(Protocol, nn.Module):
    def forward(
        self,
        x: Tensor,
        h: dict[str, Tensor],
        node_mask: Tensor,
        edge_mask: Optional[Tensor] = None,
        context: Optional[Tensor] = None,
    ) -> tuple[Tensor, dict[str, Tensor]]:
        ...
```

The code seems to run but I'm getting a typing error:

```
Protocol class "Type[DiffusionModel]" cannot derive from non-protocol class "Type[Module]"
```

How would I structure it if I wanted something like this?

Comment: Why do you want to create a Protocol class of pytorch nn.Module ? If you inherit from nn.Module, it automatically has the forward method to be overridden by you.

Comment: There are additional methods (for sampling etc) that I want to call as part of the training process that aren't by default part of the nn.Module super class, and so I wanted to create a protocol for any diffusion model that has those methods while maintaining the convenience of inheriting from nn.Module (and also to specify the return type of the forward call)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a protocol that defines the required methods and attributes for a PyTorch model, you can define it separately. here is a general example:

```
class DiffusionModelProtocol(Protocol):
    def forward(
        self,
        x: Tensor,
        h: dict[str, Tensor],
        node_mask: Tensor,
        edge_mask: Optional[Tensor] = None,
        context: Optional[Tensor] = None,
    ) -> tuple[Tensor, dict[str, Tensor]]:
        

class DiffusionModel(nn.Module, DiffusionModelProtocol):
    def forward(
        self,
        x: Tensor,
        h: dict[str, Tensor],
        node_mask: Tensor,
        edge_mask: Optional[Tensor] = None,
        context: Optional[Tensor] = None,
    ) -> tuple[Tensor, dict[str, Tensor]]:
        # Your implementation
```